# EmguCv up-to-date camera calibration project

Tags: c#, camera-calibration, emgucv

Does anybody know an up-to-date camera calibration project like http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Camera_Calibration for the current version of EmguCV (3.0.0)? I need to figure out the coefficients of distortion of a special camera. **It would be okay to have a standalone binary.** It would also be nice, if there is a documentation about which camera-distorion-model is used.

The problem behind the project above is, that it is not up-to-date with current EmguCv, so I can't build it.

The target is to correct the lense-distorsion in my own 3D engine for a constant camera. I tried to use the formulas at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_%28optics%29 with guessed parameters, but the result is still not satisfying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I updated the camera calibration project to work with EmguCV 3.0.0. The code is in [GitHub](https://github.com/luizcorreia/Camera-Calibration).

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library should not merely include a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, but [also be accompanied by usage notes or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605).